# Error installing Laravel app on webhost

Tags: laravel, installation

I'm trying to install a laravel app i'v been developping on to my webhost.
So what i've done so far is moved al the public files into the public level and the other app folders/files to the domain level folder. I also changed the paths in bootstrap path.php and public/index.php they should be right i guess.. So now whats actually wrong when I go to the site this is what i Get: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/samscbl114/domains/samschuddinck.be/l4fifa_base/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 3242

And seems there are alot of different errors in that file according to my webhost but locally evrything just works fine. So I've searching for tuts to do it the right way but can't find any good ones.

But maybe a question is if i have to install anything like composer or something on my webhost. And how ? Cause I can't use ssh on my whost.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your server's PHP version meets Laravel's minimum requirements. Laravel 4.1 requires PHP >= 5.3.7, Laravel 4.2 requires PHP >= 5.4.

I saw this error recently, and it was due to installing Laravel 4.2 on a virtual machine with PHP 5.3.x. The error is from Laravel utilizing PHP Traits, which are not supported by that version of PHP.

Comment: For the record, "laravel" 4.1 works on any version of 5.3 - you only need 5.3.7+ for the encryption stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION ...
```

This error (unexpected TOKEN **USE**) raises because of `use` keyword, for example:

<strike>use Vendor\Package\MyClass;</strike>

```
class MyClsass {

    use TraitName; // it's complaining for this line; expected a function here

}
```

In this case, it's complaining for the use of <strike>`namespace`</strike> [trait](https://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and <strike>`namespace`</strike> `trait` is available in `PHP` since version <strike>`5.3.0`</strike> `5.4.0`, so it's obvious that, on your `webhost` the required version of `PHP` is not installed, it's prior to <strike>`PHP - 5.3.0`</strike> `PHP - 5.4.0`, so you need at least <strike>`5.3.0`</strike> `5.4.0` for <strike>`namespace`</strike> `trait` support.

Comment: If it is expecting a function, it's likely it's getting hung up on trying to use a trait, in which case he will need `php 5.4`.

Comment: You are right, I've updated it. Thanks for pointing out that @user3158900 :-)